# Saving a .csv in Excel converts to a .tsv

Tags: excel

I have a simple test csv file:

[image]

If I open this file in Excel, delete column 2 and click the save icon, close and reopen the file, it converts it to a tab delimited, rather than comma delimited file. I've reproduced this on two machines.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried saving it as `CSV (MS-DOS)`, or `(Macintosh)` depending on your platform?

Comment: What kind of file are you saving this as?

Comment: I'm not trying to Save As... Trying to figure out why just saving a .csv changes the delimiters from commas to tabs

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in Notepad and see what it uses, if it's the tab then you need to change the regional settings on the computer:

```
Change the separator in all .csv text files:
1) In Microsoft Windows, click the Start button, and then click Control Panel.
2) Open the dialog box for changing Regional and Language settings.
3) Type a new separator in the List separator box.
4) Click OK twice.
```

Comment: The List Separator on Windows 10 is under Region... Additional Settings and it is set to comma (,). The original csv in Notepad contains commas. After editing and saving it contains <tab>s for delimiters